# Testable code with ORM factory

Tags: php, unit-testing

I'm trying to improve the following code for testability.

```
public function can_apply_extension()
{

    $search_dates = [
        Carbon::createFromTimestamp(strtotime($this->billing_verified_to))->subMonth(1),
        $this->billing_verified_to
    ];

    $record = ORM::factory('a model')
                 ->where('created_at', 'BETWEEN', $search_dates)
                 ->find();

    if( !$record->loaded() ) 
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;

}
```

Here's how I think I can improve it:

```
public function can_apply_extension($search_from = null, $search_to = null)
{

    $search_from = is_null($search_from) ? Carbon::createFromTimestamp(strtotime($this->billing_verified_to))->subMonth(1) : $search_from;
    $search_to = is_null($search_to) ? $this->billing_verified_to : $search_to

    $search_dates = [$search_from, $search_to];

    $record = ORM::factory('a model')
                 ->where('created_at', 'BETWEEN', $search_dates)
                 ->find();

    if( !$record->loaded() ) 
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;

}
```

I still have to mock ORM part. I think the only option is that I pass an object as a parameter or make a method that injects the ORM object.

Are there any other better ways? I'm aware of IoC container, but I can't use it in our current environment.

**Update**: Beside passing ORM as a parameter so that I can just swap it out, I found another workaround.

Since `ORM::factory()` actually returns an object, I was able to add a method and modify the factory method.

```
public function testing($bool)
{ 
    $this->_testing = $bool;
}

public function instead($when_this_passed, ORM $use_this_instead)
{
    $this->_instead_map[$when_this_passed] = $use_this_instead;
}

public function factory($name)
{
    if($this->_testing && array_key_exists($name, $this->_instead_map))
    {
        return $this->_instead_map[$name];
    } 
    else
    {
        parent::factory($name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Get rid of all the static calls, because an `ORM::factory` implies a static property that holds a reference to an object. Testing classes with static properties is hard... really hard

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem // Thank you for the input. As I mentioned, that's one of the options. Are there any others?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I've not coded in PHP recently, my examples are Java or Java-like pseudocode.)

In his *Working Effectively with Legacy Code* book *Michael C. Feathers* describes a lot of techniques which help making any code testable. Another good resource is the following article: [Killing the Helper class, part two](https://web.archive.org/web/20150908205246/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nickmalik/archive/2005/09/07/462054.aspx)

The usual way to breaking static dependencies is the following: Create a non-static interface which has a similar method than the original static class:

```
public interface OrmFactory {
    OrmSomething create($name);
}
```

Then create an implementation which calls the static method/class:

```
public class OrmFactoryImpl implements OrmFactory {
    public OrmSomething create($name) {
        return ORM::factory($name);
    }
}
```

Finally, use the interface in the `can_apply_extension` function:

```
public class MyClass {

    private OrmFactory ormFactory;

    public MyClass(OrmFactory ormFactory) {
        this.ormFactory = ormFactory;
    }

    public void can_apply_extension() {
        ...
        $record = ormFactory.create('a model')
                     ->where('created_at', 'BETWEEN', $search_dates)
                     ->find();
        ...
    }
}
```

In tests you can pass a mocked `OrmFactory` to the class while in production code you can use the original one through the `OrmFactoryImpl` wrapper/delegate. (I guess PHP also has some mocking framework implementations which makes testing easier but you can implement a `TestOrmFactory` which emulates some behaviour of the original one without the need of any database.)

The second snippet in the question has [test logic in production](http://xunitpatterns.com/Test%20Logic%20in%20Production.html) smell. I would avoid that and use the much cleaner dependency breaking above. The linked page contains some disadvantages of the smell. One of them is the following:

> Code that was not designed to work in production
> and which has not been verified to work properly
> in the production environment could accidently be
> run in production and cause serious problems.

And another one is:

> Software that is added to the SUT For Tests Only
> makes the SUT more complex. It can confuse potential
> clients of the software's interface by introducing
> additional methods that are not intended to be
> used by any code other than the tests. This
> code may have been tested only in very specific
> circumstances and might not work in the typical
> usage patterns used by real clients.

(SUT means System Under Test, in this case the class with `can_apply_extension()`.)